# How to publish a page programmatically without creating a (new) revision?

Tags: wagtail

I create/update Wagtail pages on a schedule from an external data source. Currently the wagtail page instances are published via:

```py
page_obj.save_revision().publish()
```

This works, but it seems that each time one of these page instances gets published, a new revision is created - and I don't want/need these revision objects in this specific case.

Omitting `save_revision()` results in `Page.publish() missing 1 required positional argument: 'revision'`.

*How can I publish a Wagtail page instance programmatically without revisions?*

### Things I tried

#### Use only `add_child()` and `save()`?

My second best solution is to just call `add_child()` for new page instances which seems to set the `live=True` page attribute and therefor "publishes" the page. An initial revision is created, but on further `page_obj.save()` calls for existing pages no additional revisions are created.

Hints in https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/models/__init__.py#L1413:

> New pages should generally be saved via the `add_child()  or` add_sibling() method of an existing page, which will correctly set the `path` and `depth` fields on the new page before saving it.

This seems to get the job done, but I do not know if this is the recommended method:

```py
try:
    page_obj = PageModel.objects.get(...)
    page_obj.save()
except PageModel.DoesNotExist:
    page_obj = PageModel()
    parent_page = ...
    parent_page.add_child(instance=page_obj)
```